# Submitting with jquery validate, even if valid() returns false

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

Having trouble with the submission handler and actually submitting.  The desired functionality is as follows:

Click the submit button, if there are errors, give them a dialog and the option to continue (Yes).  If Yes, run submit() after setting a specific value.  The Dialog isn't popping up at the moment, and previously I had it popping up without the submission handler, but submit() would not follow through in its action, literally do nothing.

Thanks for the help.

```
function nextDialog(form) { 
    var isValid = $('#form').valid(); 
    if (!isValid)
    {
        $('#dialog').dialog({
            resizable : false,
            width : 350,
            height : 200,
            modal : true,
            buttons : {
                "Yes" : function() {
                    $('input#foo').val('true');
                    $(this).dialog("close");
                    $('#form').submit();
                },
                "No": function() {
                    $( this ).dialog( "close" );
                    $('#form').submit();
                }
            }
        });
        return false;
    }
}
$(document).ready(function() { 
    $('.form-submit-next').click(function() {
        $('#form').validate({ 
            debug: false, 
            errorPlacement: function(error, element) {},  
            submitHandler : nextDialog
       });
    })
});
```

Comment: just a note: `submitHandler : nextDialog` is this right? can you flick a fiddle please. `:)`

Comment: Don't use `$('#form').submit();` to submit the form, unless you want to run the validation again. To submit without validation use `form.submit();`

Comment: I didn't understand your question well. Could you please clarify? Separating the current behavior and desired behavior in separate paragraphs, if possible